# Does material-ui useStyles really requires the entire props object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

According to the [DOCS](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles), if we want our component to support style overrides with `classes` we should pass the entire `props` object to the `useStyles` hook:

```
function Nested(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  const { someProp1, someProp2, ...rest } = props;
  return (...);
}
```

This is forcing us to destructure the props inside the component's body instead of inside the component's signature.

After some short playing around, i found out that all `useStyles` really needs to support the `classes` feature is to pass it an object with the `classes` prop:

```
function Nested({ someProp1, someProp2, classes ...rest }) {
  const localClasses = useStyles({ classes });
  return (...);
}
```

While this seems to work just fine, i'm wondering if i am missing something. I'm not sure if the DOCs are too defensive or trying to keep it short and simple, maybe they wanted to save us from renaming our local classes variable and it might as well just say: "Pass an object that holds the `classes` prop..." or something like that. But maybe there is more to it and i'm missing something crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `useStyles()` function that is returned from `makeStyles` [just takes an optional object](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L204) (which could be `props`). I didn't dig into it too much, but at first glance I don't see any expectations that you're actually passing any specific object/properties.

Check out the links here to the source code for more info

[Here are the types](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.d.ts)

```
import { ClassNameMap, Styles, WithStylesOptions } from '@material-ui/styles/withStyles';
import { DefaultTheme } from '../defaultTheme';

export default function makeStyles<
  Theme = DefaultTheme,
  Props extends object = {},
  ClassKey extends string = string,
>(
  styles: Styles<Theme, Props, ClassKey>,
  options?: Omit<WithStylesOptions<Theme>, 'withTheme'>,
): keyof Props extends never
  ? // `makeStyles` where the passed `styles` do not depend on props
    (props?: any) => ClassNameMap<ClassKey>
  : // `makeStyles` where the passed `styles` do depend on props
    (props: Props) => ClassNameMap<ClassKey>;
```

Comment: yet it wont work without the `classes` prop, i am wondering if in some cases it needs any other props.